# WPE WebKit Cog isn’t working: “Could not open EGL display”

Tags: webkit, egl, wayland, flatpak, wpe

I’m trying to run WPE WebKit on Ubuntu using VMware and host macOS, but I’m receiving the following error message:

```
➜  flatpak run org.wpe.Cog -P fdo http://www.example.com

(cog:2): GLib-CRITICAL **: 09:34:38.938: g_source_destroy: assertion 'source != NULL' failed

** (cog:2): WARNING **: 09:34:38.939: Platform setup failed: Could not open EGL display (0x3000)

** (cog:2): CRITICAL **: 09:34:38.939: WebKitWebViewBackend* webkit_web_view_backend_new(wpe_view_backend*, GDestroyNotify, gpointer): assertion 'backend' failed

** (cog:2): ERROR **: 09:34:38.939: Could not instantiate any WPE backend.
```

I’m running Wayland:

```
➜ pwd              
/run/user/1000
➜ ls | grep wayland
wayland-0
wayland-0.lock
```

And I installed Weston from `apt`.

But it isn’t working yet. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Hi macabeus, we are seeing the same issue. Did you ever get it working? Any tips? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

export G_MESSAGES_DEBUG=all

provides more context for this issue

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this inside a running weston session? You'd need to open a terminal there.

Comment: Yeah. Even when there is a Weston window opened it isn't work